# What is the reaction between crystal violet and bleach (sodium hypochlorite) and what is the mechanism of its action against crystal violet?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, dye, absorbance

I'm trying to find the reaction between bleach (sodium hypochlorite) and crystal violet, and need to find the mechanism of its action, as during my lab investigation the bleach did cause the crystal violet to lose its color but at a very slow rate of reaction, this was done by measuring the rate of absorbance using a colorimeter and the independent variable is the temperature.
There have been studies showing its rate of order but not the mechanism at which sodium hypochlorite discolors crystal violet, and there have been some studies claiming that it has no action.

Comment: I think you can find this article useful:  Nathanael Kazmierczak and Douglas A. Vander Griend, Improving Student Results in the Crystal Violet Chemical Kinetics Experiment. Journal of Chemical Education 2017 94 (1), 61-66 DOI: 10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00408